# Bean CDI com @SessionScoped inicializa mais de uma vez

Tags: jsf, cdi

Criei um *bean* CDI com escopo de sessão (`@SessionScoped`). O problema é que está passando pelo construtor diversas vezes, sendo que deveria ser apenas uma vez enquanto o usuário estivesse logado, correto?

Já cheguei a mudar o construtor para um método (`@PostConstruct`), mas não resolveu.

Com isso, os atributos que deveriam ser inicializados apenas uma vez, estão sendo inicializados diversas vezes, dando erros como `nullpointer`.

Estou utilizando CDI com JSF, PrimeFaces 6, JPA e WildFly 10.

```
    package br.com.transportesalvorada.security.controll;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.Collection;

    import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
    import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
    import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
    import javax.inject.Named;

    import org.primefaces.model.menu.MenuModel;
    import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
    import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;

    import br.com.transportesalvorada.security.bean.util.CriaMenus;
    import br.com.transportesalvorada.security.bean.util.ManipulacaoProperties;
    import br.com.transportesalvorada.security.configall.UsuarioSistema;
    import br.com.transportesalvorada.securityadmin.util.FacesUtil;
    import java.io.Serializable;

    @Named
    @SessionScoped
    public class SecurityControllerLogado implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private Long idLogado = 0L;
        private UsuarioSistema usuarioLogado;
        private String grupos = "";
        private MenuModel menu;
        private String versao = "";

// corpo do bean

}
```